# Python C/C++ Wrappers versus Pure C/C++ Performance

Tags: python, c++, performance, cython

I've been doing some projects in computer graphics that have revolved around using open source libraries written and C/C++ that were then turned into wrappers for python.

I want to know if the performance gains for turning it into pure C/C++ would be worth the significant time it would take to rewrite the code base.

I also know C/C++ is almost always faster than python, but considering the libraries are already a C/C++ wrapper I'm not sure how much of a performance increase I should expect. I'm not looking for an exact answer since it very much depends on the circumstances, but if anyone has a general rule of thumb that'd be great!

Answer (score 5):

Without seeing the code, in general it depends on

- the granularity of the API, i.e. how much work is done by Python in relation to native code (or how often is control returning to Python),
- whether Python code is on the critical path (some computer graphics libraries run the hot path in a separate, entirely native thread),
- whether any compromise with regard to data structure in order to interface with Python was put in place.

Generally speaking, with a well-designed Python native library, there is little, if anything, to gain in terms of performance.

So I would start by [profiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582336/how-can-you-profile-a-python-script) the Python code, to see if there is anything to gain.

Note also that C++ code is not fast by definition; it is only fast when it was engineered to be fast.

Comment: The final statement is key.

Comment: Thanks! I know this wasn't an amazing question (due to my lack of knowledge and specificity), but this gives me a great place to start!